# Find class marked with annotation of a specific value

Tags: java, reflection, reflections

I'm using this Java Reflections API that I'm finding quite convenient so far:

https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections

Find all classes marked with a specific annotation is dead easy, however, I can't figure out how to add a filter in the scanner to retrieve classes that have that annotation configured in a certain way.

For example, if I have three classes:

```
@Important(level="high")
public class HighlyImportant { }

@Important(level="medium")
public class ModeratelyImportant { }

@Important(level="low")
public class NotSoImportant { }
```

I can get all three classes by scanning for the @Important annotation, but how do I restrict that to only @Important(level=high) ?

Thanks

Comment: maybe this helps: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/annotations.html

Comment: Not a solution but a workaround: get the annotations from the resolved classes and check the values yourself.

Comment: Looking at the sources there seems to be a method `getTypesAnnotatedWith(final Annotation annotation)`. You might be able to use this by passing in a new anonymous instance of `Important` which returns the level as needed.

Comment: Ah yes, didn't notice you could do that rather than just pass the Annotation type. Thanks a lot ! (if you want to post that as an actual answer rather than a comment, I'll gladly mark it as accepted).